# Tomcat 7: Migration from Tomcat 6 - Invoker Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

Actually i'm working with an old Web Application (it's development has 10 years). Earlier, the webapp worked in Tomcat 5.x and, actually it's working in Tomcat 6 (6.0.28) and it's using the "[evil](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/InvokerServlet)" Invoker Servlet.

We are trying to migrate to Tomcat 7, and searching a way to get invoker servlet [work](http://blogs.nologin.es/rickyepoderi/index.php?/archives/44-Tomcat-7-and-the-Invoker-Servlet.html) we've seen that it's complicated (And, the "solution" it's quite similar to map every Servlet in web.xml file).

Today, the project has about 2600 classes, and we have a serious problem: Map every servlet.

Question: is there a way to "optimize" the mapping of the complete application? I don't know, some tool that can help me to get the qualified name of every servlet. I'm on charge of this project, and i don't know how to begin with this...

**Another Problem:** We don't have the complete source code, actually, if i want to do any change in the webapp, i must "Decompile" the .class file (we're using Gel for decompile .class files), repair any error and compile the file again, so, [Servlet 3.0 Annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations) for mapping doesn't seems a good idea.

Any suggestions are gladly accepted.

**Edit:** Now, i will try to Map every servlet. But, i have a question: This task can be done in a different file than web.xml? This question is because of the extense list of servlets, and the future management of this file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I'm sorry if i've asked a "no-sense" question. The Only way to solve this was mapping every servlet in web.xml file.

After an extensive search googling and, through stackoverflow, there's no other option than the [WebServlet annotation](http://www.javabeat.net/2008/12/new-features-in-servlets-3-0/) or web.xml mapping.

There's no easy way, and "recreate" the invoker servlet wasn't a practical option.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: If you are generating the same text for all of the entries, you can use `m4` to make it easier - and use `make` to generate the file. You could create a `web.m4` and run `m4` against that file using `make` to generate your `web.xml`.